# div centered with jQuery

Tags: jquery, this

I have this piece of jQuery code that center a div into it's parent.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function move_div(){
        parent_width = $('.holder').parent().width();
        parent_height = $('.holder').parent().height();

        obj_width = $('.holder').width();
        obj_height = $('.holder').height();

        $('.holder').css('top', (parent_height / 2) - (obj_height / 2)).css('left', (parent_width / 2) - (obj_width / 2));
    }
        move_div();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        move_div();
    });
});
```

I wanted to use this on multiple div's but couldn't because the code only grab the height + width of the first div with the class 'holder' ... can anyone help solve this... ?

Comment: a loop would probably help.

Comment: Are they all called `.holder`? Use `$('.holder').each()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through all the elements one by one.

`$(this)` refers to the current element with class `holder`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function move_div() {
        $('.holder').each(function () {
            parent_width = $(this).parent().width();
            parent_height = $(this).parent().height();

            obj_width = $(this).width();
            obj_height = $(this).height();
            $(this).css('top', (parent_height / 2) - (obj_height / 2)).css('left', (parent_width / 2) - (obj_width / 2));
        });
    }
    move_div();
    $(window).resize(function () {
        move_div();
    });
});
```